# LVM: expand volume size (disk is full)

Tags: linux

I have one Scenario. I have LVM root volume and it size is 50Gb. The root volume is formatted as XFS. Now my disk is full. So I need to extend volume size. I have 900GB LVM volume but it has already configured VG. Is it possible to extend the volume VG to VG?

Answer (score 1):

The question is, does the VG containing your root logical volume (LV) have any unallocated space in it? If not, then you have to either add a new physical volume (PV) to the same VG that contains the LV you wish to extend, or extend the existing PV first if possible.

A new physical volume could be a new disk, or a new (or repurposed) partition on an existing disk. Extending a PV is more common if using SAN LUNs or virtual disks in a VM, but if there is free space located immediately after the end of the current PV, it might be possible, but will probably require at least one reboot.

You cannot extend a LV from one VG to another VG.

If you are setting up a single stand-alone system, you probably should have only one VG unless you have specific reasons to do otherwise. Those reasons might include:

- a known requirement that a particular disk (or set of disks) must be able to be disconnected from the system and moved elsewhere **with the data still on them**. (If you want to move data from one system to another on LVM disks, then all the disks belonging to a single VG must normally be moved together.)
- the disks have very different performance or other properties and you don't want to treat them all as equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a good solution for that (on the block layer).

In theory you could (if both LVs are empty or rather their data can be destroyed) create new PVs in these two LVs and put them in a new VG and create a larger LV in them...

Or you do not use the LVs directly any more but put a device mapper device on top of them (this would even keep the data on the small one). But there is no standard way of doing that so you would need a boot script to set this up (and remove it).

I am not familiar with XFS but I would assume that you can extend it over several block devices. That would probably be the easiest way.